# Special Katsudon table with a light?

Tags: culture, food

Based on the text below, apparently there is a special type of table in some Japanese restaurants made for eating Katsudon.

```
どうしてレストランのテーブルにデスクランプがあるんだろう。
デスクランプのあるテーブルを挟んで座るって、なんだか取調室を連想させる。カツ丼専用席だろうか。
```

But why would tables for eating Katsudon have a light in the middle? Why would you want to lighten up just Katuson and not other foods?

I did some online searches and can't seem to figure out what the reason for this is.

Comment: Great question! http://ncode.syosetu.com/n6819cy/4/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「デスクランプのあるテーブルを挟んで座る」(Sitting face to face at a table/desk with a desk light on it) reminds us of 警察の取り調べ室 (police interrogation room), which is often depicted in fiction like this:

[image]

And 取り調べ室 often conjures up a stereotyped image of serving かつ丼 to the suspect:

[image]

This is because this situation is (or rather, used to be) often seen in police dramas on TV.

[image]

In the real world, however, かつ丼 is never served in a police interrogation room.

参考: [Wikipedia 「カツ丼 -- 刑事ドラマ」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%84%E4%B8%BC#.E5.88.91.E4.BA.8B.E3.83.89.E3.83.A9.E3.83.9E)

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting! However, the phrase "カツ丼専用席" seems to literally imply the table in that restaurant was special designed for eating Katsudon. Is this more of a joke or sarcasm?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds to me more like a joke.

Comment: Now I'm hungry... :(

Comment: ww @istrasciさんカツ丼好きだもんねー 覚えてるよ～ :D -> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17617/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-word-katsu/17620#comment39455_17620